# application.propreties is ignored in spring

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm having a simple spring-data-jpa environemnt where I want to connect to a mysql database. Following code with the Entity:

```
@Entity
public class DbRecord extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
 private String name;

 public DbRecord(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
    return this.name;
 }
}
```

Configuration class (very simple)

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DemiConfiguration {}
```

Repository

```
public interface DemiRepository extends CrudRepository<DbRecord, Long> {}
```

and finally the test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(classes = DemiConfiguration.class)
public class SimpleTest {
 @Autowired
 DemiRepository repository;

 @Test public void testInsert() {
    DbRecord record = new DbRecord("test");
    repository.save(record);
    Iterable<DbRecord> records = repository.findAll();
 }
}
```

So far so good. The test works on hsqldb but when I try to write to an mysql database and I create an application.properties into src/main/resources/application.properites with following values:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/demi
spring.datasource.username=demi
spring.datasource.password=demi123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

The test case ignores the properties and sticks to the default configuration with hsqldb.

I am using IntelliJ as IDE.

Comment: When testing Spring Boot applications instead of `@ContextConfiguration` use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` to register some additional listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class` to the `@ContextConfiguration`. From its JavaDocs:

```
* {@link ApplicationContextInitializer} that can be used with the
* {@link ContextConfiguration#initializers()} to trigger loading of
* {@literal application.properties}.
```